# javascript xslt will not correctly post data

Tags: javascript, html, forms, xslt, submit

I am trying to submit a form using javascript (generated from an xslt stylesheet).

```
<form name='myform' action='search.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='query' />
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function submit(id)
    {
      document.myform.elements[0] = id;  *Note* I have tried document.getElementById('query').value = id;
      document.myform.submit();
    }
    </script>
</form>
```

After this code I have xsl translations formatting xml data.  I call the submit function like this:
    
          *NOTE* This href='' does nothing
      
      
        submit('somequery')

When I click on the href the javascript function executes and seems to work fine, except NO data gets POST'ed.  I set the  value to 'somequery' but when the form gets POST'ed, the value is '' (blank).

Why does it do this?  I have tried createElement('input') and such from within javascript but I cannot ever get the form to POST the input value.

Comment: where is this function being called from?

Comment: did you mean  document.myform.elements[0].value?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Firefox here? The behaviour may differ between browser. Firstly, you should go back to using **getElementById**

```
document.getElementById('query').value = id;
```

The reason this may not have worked is that your hidden element does not actually specify an **id** attribute.

```
<input type='hidden' name='query' id='query' />
```

In IE, I believe it allows a lack of **id** and assumes it is equal to the **name**. In Firefox, a lack of **id** results in a javascript error when you try to do **getElementById**

```
<form name='myform' action='search.php' method='post'> 
<input type='hidden' name='query' id='query' /> 
<script type='text/javascript'> 
function submit(id) 
{ 
   document.getElementById('query').value = id; 
   document.myform.submit(); 
} 
</script> 
</form>
```